# if is phonegap load different theme at wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cordova, wordpress-theming

i want to know how can I load a different theme in my wordpress website when the access is made by a phonegap app.

So, i created a phonegap html page with a link to my wordpress theme, I want when to click at that link the wordpress load a different theme.

Comment: Are you developing the PhoneGap app yourself? If so, could you just make the request to a slightly different page URL?

Comment: @Gazzini yes its me developping. yes i can! I try using Theme Switcher with the theme in the url (ex: mydomain.com/?theme=MyTheme ) but when i click in some link in this page the var in the url disapear :/

Answer (score 0):

Have the PhoneGap app initially append `?theme=[MY THEME]` to the end of the URL.

Then, on the WordPress side, the first page will work (as you said), but if the user then clicks another link, it no longer contains the `?theme=[MY THEME]`, so it loads a standard page.

So, on the WordPress side, implement the following logic:

```
if (theme && (theme == [MY THEME])) {
  //append the "?theme=[MY THEME]" string to the end of all the internal URL's on this page
}
```

You should use `&` instead of `?` if the link already has `get-parameters`, but anyways, best of luck!

Comment: thanks but with this i must, using javascript, get all urls in the page, vrify if they have '?' or not and then add to the end the ?theme=MYTHEME.